# RowCount in SqlAlchemy ORM does not return correct value

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I wrote such a function in Python to benefit from SqlAlchemy ORM:

```
def __validate(self, register_tipi, offset, count):
    query  = self._table.select(and_(
        self._table.c.type == register_tipi,
        self._table.c.index >= offset,
        self._table.c.index < offset + count))
    result = self._connection.execute(query)
    return result.rowcount == count
```

I try to read "count" number of rows from Sqllite db. And those rows exactly exist there. But "result.rowcount" always returns '-1'. I cant figure it out why.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, actually. I just ignored it. I had to return always " true ".